# Play framework. Action Not Found. GET instead of POST

Tags: html, scala, post, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to make POST request, but every time I get this error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U66pU.png)

I do request from a simple hyperlink in my html-file:
`<a href="@routes.UserController.deleteUser(user._1._id)"> Delete </a>`

And I can't use any forms, because I call this inside another form (forms nesting not allowed as I know):
`@helper.form(helper.CSRF(routes.UserController.submitBoxes)) {...`

Are there any solutions apart from using GET instead of POST?

Comment: Yes, you need to use javascript; there are plenty of good and easy to use ajax libraries out there.

Comment: Are there any solutions without JS?

Comment: Yes, you could do a form.

Comment: But nesting is not allowed, isn't it?

Comment: So, to answer your original question: you can generate POST requests with javascript or with a form in the browser. Outside of the browser there are plenty of possibilities, of course.

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript directly there are plenty of very nice languages that compile to javascript. ([PureScript](http://www.purescript.org/) for example)

Answer (score -1):

Click on link with href attribute always work as GET, if you not prevent this event with js. But in you case, you can just add duplicate line in you "routes" file with replace POST to GET. Like this:

```
GET   /users/$id<[^/]+>/delete  controllers.UserController.deleteUser(id: ObjectId)
```

Comment: No, please don't do this. Actions that modify state should never be invokable through the GET verb. You need to use javascript to POST to your endpoint.